# I get a CUPS Server error: 'server-error-internal-error' when I try to connect a network printer

Tags: 16.04, printing

I'm trying to add a new network printer on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After setting it's IP address it recognises that a printer is available (192.168.1.100/9100), but when I click Forward I get a CUPS server error: 'server-error-internal-error'. Can anyone help?

The printer is connected to the router and is accessible from another Windows machine.

Comment: This isn't an _answer_ but, when you run into this, look at /var/log/cups/error_log for a real error message.

Comment: @LarrikJ I did not find a useful error there unfortunately.

Answer (score 26):

I was able to work around the problem by setting up the printer using the CUPS web interface. I pointed my browser at localhost:631, which gave me the web interface. Then selected "Adding Printers and Classes", then "Add Printer".

It had already detected my network attached printer so it was just a matter of installing the correct PPD file from the selection.

I don't know why attempting to install the printer through the ubuntu Printers settings resulted in the 'server-error-internal-error', but this method seems to have worked fine. If anyone knows what the root cause of the error is I'd still love to know...

Comment: I click on Adding Printers and Classes in localhost:631 but I get Not Found error

Comment: Exactly same issue for me under Fedora 28.

Comment: I had the same issue with my Xubuntu 18.04 and this workaround helped

Comment: Yes but why must you use this instead of the normal printer interface? Is this only for old printers?

Comment: This workaround worked for me with a Canon Pixma MX455 and an Ubuntu 18.04 based distribution (although I had to use Firefox instead of Chrome to avoid an "Unauthorized" error when trying to add the printer through the CUPS web interface), after having installed the Linux drivers from the Canon site.

The original issue seems to be related to a [problem](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/5512) in CUPS, possibly with version 2.2.7, it seems like newer versions should work correctly.

Comment: Worked for me, under Ubuntu-MATE 21.04. Web Interface was accessible (admin-tab to get to add-printer... (the 'add printer' on '/' contains just the help), adding the printer and driver (w/o cups)... disabled cups, still works...

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. For Ubuntu 20.04, go to http://localhost:631/admin and click 'Add Printer'.

Comment: Had to use this workaround on 22.04. Would love to know why (a) the Printers program is slow at transitioning between the different steps when adding a printer whereas the web UI is super fast; and (b) why it fails with the `server-error-internal-error` weirdness.